# JDBC Exception JZ0BE: BatchUpdateException: A user with System Administrator (SA) role must reconfigure the system to enable Java

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I am using Sybase JDBC JConnect3 driver to insert large data in a table using Batch Insert feature of JDBC.
I am preparing a batch of 100 inserts and executing the batch. But it is throwing below error while executing batch query.

> com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybBatchUpdateException: JZ0BE: BatchUpdateException: Error occurred while executing batch statement: Cannot run this command because Java services are not enabled. A user with System Administrator (SA) role must reconfigure the system to enable Java.
>    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseBatchUpdateException(Unknown Source)
>          at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.handleBatchException(Unknown Source)
>          at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
>          at com.loader.LoadTable.loadDataToOracleFirst(LoadTable.java:367)
>          at com.loader.LoadTable.fetchDataFromSybaseFirst(LoadTable.java:246)
>          at com.loader.LoadTable.main(LoadTable.java:157)

Can anyone tell me excatly what I need to configure to resolve above issue?

Comment: Have you tried the manual?

Answer (score 1):

Start by trying:

```
sp_configure "enable java",1
```

...and restarting the service if necessary. There may be more to it than that, please provide details of your server product, version, and anything else that might be helpful.